# c++/cli ref class and dynamic allocation using handles?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

In .NET's version of C++, we can declare a class in the following way:

```
ref class CoolClass
{
  public:
      String^ GetName()
      { return name;}

      void SetName(String^ n)
      {name = n;}

  private:
      String^ name;
 }
```

When we create a class this way, instances of the class will be created and managed on the managed heap with the clr's garbage collector.

Now, lets say that I created 2 instances of the animal class.

```
Animal cat;
Animal ^dog = gcnew Animal();
```

Both of these classes operate exactly the same. Is there any real important difference between creating instances of classes one way or the other? They both SHOULD be managed code right? The first way seems so much easier and prevents me from having to use the "->" operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first syntax is called [stack semantics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms177191.aspx). This simulates stack allocation in standard C++. Upon leaving scope, including when an exception is raised, the object is automatically disposed. This is a nice syntactic convenience, but under the hood both objects are actually instantiated on the managed heap. I personally use the first syntax with disposable types only, such as database connections.

As for the differences, you will have to use the % unary operator to convert an instance declared with stack semantics to its underlying handle type if you must pass it to some method that expects a handle type.

Comment: Sorry for such a late accepted answer. Thank you so much for the help. It really helped me out a olot